# Given two sets, finding two non trivial homomorphisms that are not isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Is it possible to have two non trivial homomorphisms that are not isomorphisms for given two Groups?

I am specially interested in additive/remainder Group of Integers and multiplicative (arithmetic multiplication as group operator) group of complex roots of unity.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "*non isomorphic homomorphisms*"? Do you mean "a homomorphism from one to the other that is not an isomorphism, and the same in the other direction"? And when you say "*set*", you appear to mean group, right?

Comment: Send *all* to *one*.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, that was quiet sloppy. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the groups are isomorphic to start with and you’re asking about isomorphisms between them, you are in essence just asking about the set (group, actually) of automorphisms of a single group. This automorphism group will ordinarily be nontrivial, as is the case with the group of $n$-th roots of unity for a fixed $n>2$. If you were asking about the (countable) group of all roots of unity (in the complex numbers, for example), then the automorphism group is not even countable. So the quantitative answer to your question is, Yes, Many, Many.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider the group $(\mathbb Z_7)^*$ of nonzero elements mod $7$, where the group operation is multiplication. Both multiplication by $2$ and multiplication by $3$ give different nontrivial homomorphisms from the group to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the homomorphism $g_n:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g_n(1)=n$, where $n>0$. Then all the $g_n$'s are distinct and they are definitely not isomorphisms because $g_n(\mathbb{Z})=n\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}.$